# mv deleting files at the end instead of one by one

Tags: mv

I am moving a folder recursively between two filesystems using mv -v.
It seems like deletions happen at the end (in order to make mv *transactional* ?). I don't have enough space to hold two copies of the same folder, is there a way to force mv to delete a file as soon as it is done?

Comment: an `mv` should only allocate additional disk space if its being moved to another partition. otherwise, it just updates the inodes to indicate the new location on the partition, and neither copies nor deletes anything. if you are copying to a new partition however, its unclear to me why you can't spare the disk space as both partitions should have sufficient to hold the entire directory (or this whole proposition is never going to work because the destination is too small).

Comment: Apparently mv doesn't do things recursively. It will move each top level folder. That is good enough for me content is split evenly between top level folders anyway and I have enough room for 2 copies of each of them.
P.S. my case was related to 2 ZFS file systems on the same pool. From a mv perspective these are different, from a storage perspective it's shared. I don't know if it makes sense.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense. multi-disk aggregations do confuse the matter. unfortunately, mv won't work for you by itself, so perhaps look into alternatives like a shell script to enumerate the sub directories and process them individually (copy, delete, rinse, repeat), or  perhaps something like rsync may work better for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers and comments note, there is no such functionality in `mv`. But `rsync` has a `--remove-source-files` switch which behaves as you want, removing files from the source continuously as the operation progresses.

I'd also recommend the `-a` switch ("archive mode") to preserve (most) file metadata if you're making backups (`mv` doesn't do this if the move is between filesystems, so `rsync` is actually better in that regard).

Answer (score 1):

No, the [Man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) for `mv` do not indicate any switches that change the behavior of the command in the way you describe. You will have to look into other commands or algorithms.

> **Name**
>
> mv - move (rename) files Synopsis
>
> *mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST*
>
> *mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY*
>
> *mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY*
>   SOURCE...
>
> **Description**
>
> Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
>
> Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options
>   too.
>
> --backup[=CONTROL]
>
> ```
> make a backup of each existing destination file
> ```
>
> -b
>
> ```
> like --backup but does not accept an argument
> ```
>
> -f, --force
>
> ```
> do not prompt before overwriting
> ```
>
> -i, --interactive
>
> ```
> prompt before overwrite
> ```
>
> -n, --no-clobber
>
> ```
> do not overwrite an existing file
> ```
>
> If you specify more than one of -i, -f, -n, only the final one takes
>   effect.
>
> --strip-trailing-slashes
>
> ```
> remove any trailing slashes from each SOURCE argument
> ```
>
> -S, --suffix=SUFFIX
>
> ```
> override the usual backup suffix
> ```
>
> -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
>
> ```
> move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
> ```
>
> -T, --no-target-directory
>
> ```
> treat DEST as a normal file
> ```
>
> -u, --update
>
> ```
> move only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing
> ```
>
> -v, --verbose
>
> ```
> explain what is being done
> ```
>
> --help
>
> ```
> display this help and exit
> ```
>
> --version
>
> ```
> output version information and exit
> ```
>
> The backup suffix is '~', unless set with --suffix or
>   SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX. The version control method may be selected via
>   the --backup option or through the VERSION_CONTROL environment
>   variable. Here are the values:
>
> none, off
>
> ```
> never make backups (even if --backup is given)
> ```
>
> numbered,t
>
> ```
> make numbered backups
> ```
>
> existing, nil
>
> ```
> numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
> ```
>
> simple, never
>
> ```
> always make simple backups
> ```

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv

Comment: I hardly ever learn to use a Linux command using its man page.